# What is recursive Fourier sampling and how does it prove separations between BQP and NP in the black-box model?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, bqp, fourier-sampling

### Context:

I was going through John Watrous' lecture [Quantum Complexity Theory (Part 1) - CSSQI 2012](https://youtu.be/fc12NHko8sw?t=2895). Around 48 minutes into the lecture, he presents the following:

> **No relationship** is known between $\mathsf{BQP}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$...they are conjectured to be **incomparable**.

So far so good. Then I came across [Scott Aaronson](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/8940/scott-aaronson)'s answer to [Can a parallel computer simulate a quantum computer? Is BQP inside NP?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/34637) He mentions these points:

> - Suppose you insist on talking about decision problems only ("total"
>   ones, which have to be defined for every input), as people
>   traditionally do when defining complexity classes like P, NP, and BQP.
>   Then we have **proven separations** between BQP and NP in the "**black-box
>   model**" (i.e., the model where both the BQP machine and the NP machine
>   get access to an oracle), as **mmc alluded to**.
> - And to reiterate, all of these separations are in the **black-box model
>   only**. It remains completely unclear, even at a conjectural level,
>   whether or not these translate into separations in the "real" world
>   (i.e., the world without oracles). We don't have any clear examples
>   analogous to factoring, of real decision problems in BQP that are
>   plausibly not in NP. After years thinking about the problem, I still
>   don't have a strong intuition either that BQP should be contained in
>   NP in the "real" world or that it shouldn't be.

According to his answer, it seems that in the "**black-box model**" we can show some relationship (as in *non-overlapping*) between $\mathsf{BQP}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$. He cites [@mmc's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/34547), which says:

> There is no definitive answer due to the fact that no problem is known
> to be inside PSPACE and outside P. But [recursive Fourier sampling](http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/uncompute.pdf)
> is conjectured to be outside [MA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur%E2%80%93Merlin_protocol#MA) (the probabilistic generalization
> of NP) and has an efficient quantum algorithm. Check page 3 of [this
> survey by Vazirani](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Elomonaco/ams/lecturenotes/Vazirani.pdf) for more details.

### Question:

It's not clear from [@mmc's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/34547) as to how the **recursive Fourier sampling** algorithm is related to the $\mathsf{BQP}$ class and how (or whether at all) it proves separations between $\mathsf{BQP}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$ in the "**black-box model**". In fact, I'm not even sure what "**black-box model**" means in this context, although I suspect that it refers to some kind of computation model involving [quantum oracles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/concepts/oracles?view=qsharp-preview).

It would be great if someone could provide a brief and digestible summary of what the **recursive Fourier sampling** algorithm is and how it proves separations between $\mathsf{BQP}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$. Even a rough sketch of the idea behind the proof would be okay. I'm hoping this will give me a head start in understanding the papers linked by [@mmc](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1656/mmc), which are otherwise rather dense for me at present.

Answer (score 2):

Initially I'll admit that I find the linked papers to be dense as well.

However, to make some headway, a complete problem in $\mathrm{NP}$ can be phrased as "given a $\mathsf{3SAT}$ instance, does there exist a solution?"  A complete problem in $\mathrm{coNP}$ is "given $\mathsf{3SAT}$ instance, do all inputs satisfy the $\mathsf{3SAT}$?  Problems in the polynomial hierarchy $\mathrm{PH}$ alternate "there exists" with "for alls," with a constant number of iterations of $\exists$ and $\forall$. For me, the easiest problem in $\mathrm{PH}$ to think about is "is there a mate in $n$ for this board position?" because this is just "does there exist a move by white such that for all moves by black, there is a counter-move by white such that... white wins."

Ponder the difficulty of such $\forall x_1,\exists x_2\cdots$ problems as compared to factoring, which is in $\mathrm{NP}\cap\mathrm{coNP}$.

Turning to Recursive Fourier Sampling (RFS), much as in Simon's problem, with RFS we are only given oracle access to a function $A$.    However, RFS involves a promise having *just such an alternation* of $\exists$ and $\forall$.  By going up to a small-enough height (number of iterations of $\exists$ and $\forall$,) the problem can be shown to be likely difficult for a classical computer to efficiently solve but definitely easy for a quantum computer to solve.

Comparing RFS to the "forrelation" problem that I think is a little easier to understand but somewhat more difficult to see the connection to $\forall x_1,\exists x_2\cdots$.  Forrelation is as simple as asking if, given two black-box (oracle) functions $f$ and $g$, is there a correlation between $f$ and the Fourier transform of $g$?  Here, we can simply Fourier transform $g$ and find the inner product with $f$.

Forrelation is likely even *completely outside* the polynomial hierarchy.  Here the relation to the $\forall, \exists$ is less clear to me right now but effectively involves translating a tree of alternating $\mathsf{AND's}$ and $\mathsf{OR's}$ that are capable of solving forrelation to a sequence of alternating $\forall$ and $\exists$.

Here $f$ and $g$ are simply black-box, without any structure.  As far as I know, we don't know a good instantiation of $f$ or $g$ "in the real world" yet, with $f$ and/or $g$ have a particular structure.